# GDAL Planet data request returns "HTTP error code: 411"

Tags: gdal, planet

I've been able to successfully download Planet scenes through the Open California initiative without any issues until yesterday. Here is an example where I'm trying to get the metadata of a scene:

```
gdalinfo "PLScenes:ITEMTYPES=PSScene4Band,SCENE=20180601_181054_1029,ASSET=analytic_sr" -oo API_KEY=$MYAPIKEY
```

Here is the error output:

> `ERROR 1: HTTP error code : 411 
>   ERROR 1: <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html lang=en>
>     <meta charset=utf-8>
>     <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
>     <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
>     <style>
>       *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
>     </style>
>     <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
>     <p><b>411.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
>     <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>`

This happens with any GDAL related request from the Planet API, whether getting metadata via gdalinfo or trying to download via gdal_translate. I am using GDAL v2.2.2, and a colleague confirms that they are still able to successfully download scenes via GDAL.

Comment: The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 411 Length Required client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content-Length header. Do you send a content header?

Comment: As Luke mentioned, please provide the command line parameters for `gdalinfo` as text for testing purposes. Can you also note what version of GDAL you are using?

Comment: @Mapperz I don't provide a content header. I have not needed to provide one in the past and the docs don't seem to indicate that one is needed: https://www.gdal.org/drv_plscenes_data_v1.html

Comment: @bosth updated text formatting and added clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in GDAL master and will be in release 2.3.2 later this month ([git commit](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/43e57d2c46ada25cc131214519a06a2c33cec155)).

For the time being, I will note that the error will only occur when the asset is *inactive*, so if you attempt `gdalinfo` on a item that is already activated, you should get the normal interactions.

Also, you might want to try Planet's Python client, which includes a command line utility that lets you search for and download data: https://github.com/planetlabs/planet-client-python.